# jQuery.ajax() blocked due to CSP within WebExtension

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox-addon, content-security-policy, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a Mozilla Firefox extension, which needs to communicate with my server on localhost:8080.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: query_method,
        url: "http://localhost:8080/item",
        data: item,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(result) {
            return result.code;
        },
        error: function(request, status) {
            /*
             todo handle internal error
             */
            console.log(request);
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
```

Thanks to the CSP, I cannot use `jQuery.ajax()` to `GET/POST/DELETE/PUT`. It all gives me the following error message:

```
Content Security Policy: 
The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at
http://localhost:8080/... 
("script-src moz-extension://a79d13c4-898a-482a-9bc9-d016e8dae8f5
https://* moz-extension: blob: filesystem: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'").
```

And of course, I've tried some so-called *solutions* like:

- `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; report-uri http://localhost:8080"` -> no use
- `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self' http:"` -> `Error processing content_security_policy: SyntaxError: ‘object-src’ directive contains a forbidden http: protocol source`

Could anybody give a real solution to send HTTP request and receive data from a Firefox extension?

Why is using jQuery.ajax()` *loading a resource*? If so, I cannot use HTTP protocol to do any request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that an XHR is blocked by CSP, it is that you're using jquery and jsonp. Webextensions can perform cross-origin XHRs if you [allow them in the manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#Cross-origin_access), but [jsonp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#How_JSONP_works) attempts to evaluate the resource as a `<script>` tag instead of actually performing an XHR.

Ditch jquery, allow localhost in the manifest and use standardized APIs such as XHR or [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch)